# How to Profile a Java Application running in a DEA in CloudFoundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a Java Application deployed in Cloud Foundry DEA. I want to profile the application by tunneling in to the DEA. I found lot of support for Diego but currently we have it running in DEA.
Also how to generate the Thread dumps for an app running in DEA in CF?

Answer (score 0):

I had built a plugin for CF to do this a while back but it doesn't work anymore due to the way it created a new instance to SSH to. However, you can still use the script it used to fire up a [tmate](http://tmate.io) session to connect to. Try re-pushing your application with the following options:

`-u none -c 'curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danhigham/cf-console/master/install.sh > /tmp/install.sh && bash /tmp/install.sh && sleep infinity'`

for example `cf push show-headers -u none -c 'curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danhigham/cf-console/master/install.sh > /tmp/install.sh && bash /tmp/install.sh && sleep infinity'`

The call to 'sleep' will ensure the container stays up after calling tmate. When the push is successful, take a look in the logs for a line that looks like this;

```
2016-09-01T08:01:36.70+0100 [APP/0]      OUT ./include/event2/util.h
2016-09-01T08:01:36.70+0100 [APP/0]      OUT ./bin/tmate
2016-09-01T08:01:50.21+0100 [APP/0]      OUT debZng8rwCKi7M7MCVXXI9kuJ@ny2.tmate.io
```

The third line here shows an SSH address that you should be able to connect to the container through `ssh debZng8rwCKi7M7MCVXXI9kuJ@ny2.tmate.io`. You should connect to a tmux session with two panes, one with a bash shell and one with the command run by the associated buildpack. Needless to say, the better solution above all of this, would be to use Diego cells instead of DEAs ;-)